# Apply branding Content Search web part

Tags: content-search-web-part

I have created a content search web part in my landing page of my SP 2013 site collection.
This shows all the subsites under this site collection.The end user says, the default look and feel of this CSWP is not good.

How can i change the look and feel by applying branding/css to this CSWP?
When i went to the edit the web part pane, i am not seeing any option for setting the color coding/apply css/refer js files.
Is there any way, I can do this?Though I heard about apply the display templates in this cswp, am not getting where to start with.

I checked [Here](http://www.abelsolutions.com/totm/creating-a-custom-content-search-web-part-to-display-news-articles-with-images/) , but didn't have much info. on this link

Answer (score 1):

We can change the look and feel of Content Search web part using display templates. So you have to create custom display template according to your requirements. following are some helpful articles,

http://blogs.technet.com/b/sharepoint_quick_reads/archive/2013/09/03/3588171.aspx

http://blogs.technet.com/b/sharepoint_quick_reads/archive/2013/08/02/sharepoint-2013-customize-display-template-for-content-by-search-web-part-cswp-part-2.aspx

http://www.sharemuch.com/2014/07/23/how-to-customize-the-look-of-the-sharepoint-content-search-web-part-results/